# Using laravel, how do I create a view that will update a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

I've got 2 models, Contact and Email. Any contact may have multiple email address, so I've created a one-to-many relationship in the models:

```
class Contact extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required'
    );

    public function emails() {
        return $this->hasMany('Email');
    }

}

class Email extends Eloquent {

    public function emails() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Contact');
    }

}
```

Hopefully I'm on the right track so far...

I've used Jeff Way's scaffolding for the Contact model, so I've got this update method in the controller:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
    $validation = Validator::make($input, Contact::$rules);

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        $contact = $this->contact->find($id);
        $contact->update($input);

        return Redirect::route('contacts.show', $id);
    }

    return Redirect::route('contacts.edit', $id)
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

Also, I've modified the edit view to show all of the emails associated with the contact, and then an additional blank input to add a new one:

```
@foreach($emails as $key => $email)
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email '.$key.':') }}
        {{ Form::text('email'.$email->id, $email->email) }}
    </li>
    @if(count($emails)==$key+1)
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email '.($key+1).':') }}
        {{ Form::text('email'.($email->id+1)) }}
    </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Now, I have no idea how to go about modifying the update method to update the emails (if modified) and add a new one (if entered). I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction - thanks!

Comment: You can use `push()` method for Saving A Model And Relationships [link](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

Comment: Thanks, this might be in the right direction, I'm not sure - but I definitely need some more help with this. How do I have it update the appropriate rows in the emails table and add one if it doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this isn't necessarily a Laravel-specific answer.

No matter what, you need handle syncing the contact's emails with what's submitted in the form:

Two tactics:

1. Delete all emails associated with the contact. Then create new emails based on what's in the form. That way, you're always inserting new emails.
2. Get all emails associated with the contact. Iterate through them. If the ID of the submitted email (from the form) matches an existing email, update that email address. If a email is new (has no ID associated with it), create a new one. This option likely requires a nested loop, and should technically be frowned upon - however, for small numbers of emails, it's not a big deal.

Now, to get Laravel(4)-specific

Eloquent has a handy `sync()` method to handle updating relationships - however, I believe it's only for many to many relationships, and therefore relies on a "pivot table".

Eloquent also has a `push()` method, but since I haven't yet played with it, I'm not sure if it "synchronize" the related emails behind the scenes or just add new relationships. This is your best bet.

I tweeted to Laravel asking that, hoping to see an answer sonn: https://twitter.com/fideloper/status/353303438664278018

**For option 1:**

First, rename all email textfields (whether existing or new) to `email[]`. We won't care about their ID since they are getting deleted.

```
@foreach($emails as $key => $email)
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
        {{ Form::text('email[]', $email->email) }}
    </li>
@endforeach
    <!-- No need to have this in PHP logic - always give option to add new emails -->
    <!-- I'm also assuming you can name multiple new emails, perhaps with some JS -->
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'New Email:') }}
        {{ Form::text('email[]' }}
    </li>
```

**Minor note:** You may have to take care of the ID of the textfield, likely using the `$key` variable so the label `for=""` attribute matches to the correct TextField. I'll leave that up to you.

Then, in PHP you'll delete all emails associated with the $contact, and then create them like new.

```
// Delete all related emails
$contact->emails()->delete(); // I think this works. Otherwise do a manual query or loop through email email and `->delete()` them.

// Create new ones
foreach( Input::get("emails") as $email )
{
    $newEmail = new Email;
    $newEmail->email = $email;
    $contact->emails()->save($email);
}
```

**For Option 2:**

You'll know if new emails exist because they won't have an ID associated with the from the form data. I would change my inputs to be an array of emails, so it's easier to cycle through them:

```
@foreach($emails as $key => $email)
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email '.$key.':') }}
        <!-- Notice this is an array now: -->
        {{ Form::text('email['.$email->id.']', $email->email) }}
    </li>
@endforeach
    <!-- No need to have this in PHP logic - always give option to add new emails -->
    <!-- I'm also assuming you can name multiple new emails, perhaps with some JS -->
    <li>
        {{ Form::label('newemail', 'New Email:') }}
        {{ Form::text('newemail[]' }}
    </li>
```

Then in your PHP, for new emails:

```
foreach( Input::get('newemail') as $email)
{
    $newEmail = new Email();
    $newEmail->email = $email;
    $contact->emails()->save( $newEmail );
}
```

For "not new" emails, `Input::get('email')` in my example above, you will likely need to get current emails associated with the contact (`$currentEmails = $contact->emails()`) and update them as necessary in a foreach loop (not written out here).

Something like that should get you on your way to start...